# How can I create a menu entry for my snap

Tags: snap

I have an app which I packaged successfully as a snap, but I don't want my users to run it from the command-line. How can I create a menu entry for it?

Answer (score 3):

[qcomicbook in the Snappy Playpen](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/qcomicbook/setup/gui) is a good example of this. It ships an icon and a `.desktop` file in a special directory called `./setup/gui`.

For the desktop file, you can in most cases just copy the one that is shipped with the upstream source, or create one from scratch ([Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)).

Note the following when you create the `Icon` and `Exec` entries:

- For `Exec` just use whatever you defined in the `apps` stanza of the snap.
- For `Icon` use `${SNAP}/meta/gui/` because that's where the icon will be shipped.

In the example of `qcomicbook`, this is:

`Exec=qcomicbook
Icon=${SNAP}/meta/gui/qcomicbook.png`

Comment: I always forget, in the end Snap is another packaging system, and it should have similar variables like Debian & Python packaging systems. Thank you.  By the way, would you please accept your own answer, to be easier to find.